# Removing a control character using Python

Tags: python, regex, amazon-web-services, pattern-matching, control-characters

I have a script that processes the output of a command (the aws help cli command).

I step through the output line-by-line and don't start the actual real parsing until I encounter the text "AVAILABLE COMMANDS" at which point I set a flag to true and start further processing on each line.

I've had this working fine - BUT on Ubuntu we encounter a problem which is this :
The CLI **highlights** the text in a way I have not seen before:

The output is very long, so I've grep'd the particular line in question - see below:

```
># aws ec2 help | egrep '^A'
>AVAILABLE COMMANDS
># aws ec2 help | egrep '^A' | cat -vet
>A^HAV^HVA^HAI^HIL^HLA^HAB^HBL^HLE^HE C^HCO^HOM^HMM^HMA^HAN^HND^HDS^HS$
```

What I haven't seen before is that each letter that is highligted is in the format X^HX.
I'd like to apply a simple transformation of the type   X^HX --> X  (for all a-zA-Z).

What have I tried so far:
well my workaround is this - first I remove control characters like this:

```py
String = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f]','',String)
```

but I still have to search for 'AAVVAAIILLAABBLLEE' which is totally ugly. I considered using a further regex to turn doubles to singles but that will catch true doubles and get messy.

I started writing a function with an iteration across a constructed list of alpha characters to translate as described, and I used hexdump to try to figure out the exact \x code of the control characters in question but could not get it working - I could remove H but not the ^.

I really don't want to use any additional modules because I want to make this available to people without them having to install extras. In conclusion I have a workaround that is quite ugly, but I'm sure someone must know a quick an easy way to do this translation. It's odd that it only seems to show up on Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you try setting env `$GREP_OPTIONS=--color=always`?  I suspect it is set to `never` or `off` I forget.  Then `grep` does not know to process the pipe as colorized.  Or you can do `aws ec2 help | egrep --color=always '^A' | cat -vet`

Comment: You're on the right track to not homebrew a workaround.  If we do not know what causes it, we won't know how it evolves.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/help.py runs `groff -m man -T ascii` to format the output.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this a little further I was able to put in place a solution:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import ascii_uppercase


def RemoveUbuntuHighlighting(String):
        for Char in ascii_uppercase + ascii_lowercase:
                Match = Char + '\x08' + Char
                String = re.sub(Match,Char,String)
        return(String)
```

I'm still a little confounded to see characters highlighted in the format (X\x08X), the arrangement does seem to repeat the same information unnecessarily.

The other thing I would advise to anyone not familiar with reading hexcode is that each pair of hexes is swapped around with respect to the order of their appearance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; probably you used something like `od` which *displays* the hex codes in the wrong order; but they are of course in exactly the order they were output. Maybe see if you have a modern hexdump utility like `xxd`, or try `od -t x1`

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler and more reliable fix is to replace a backspace and duplicate of any character.

I have also augmented this to handle underscores using the same mechanism (character, backspace, underscore).

```py
String = re.sub(r'(.)\x08(\1|_)', r'\1', String)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/yzwd2V

This highlighting was standard back when output was to a line printer; backspacing and printing the same character again would add pigmentation to produce **boldface.** (Backspacing and printing an underscore would produce underlining.)

Probably the AWS CLI can be configured to disable this by setting the `TERM` variable to something like `dumb`. There is also a utility [`col`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/col.1.html) which can remove this formatting (try `col-b`; maybe see also `colcrt`). Though perhaps really the best solution would be to `import` the AWS Python code and extract the help message natively.